# State's property value not getting saved in const variable?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am newbie in React and i have made 2 state objects with one property each
then i tried to save the value of property inside a const variablei am getting value of one first state correctly but for unknown reason value of other is not showing up in Console Log
[image]

here are 2 state's code

```
    state = {
    count: 23,
  };
 stateTwo = {
    number: 22
  };
```

these are 2 functions for calling values in console log

```
changNumber() {
    console.log("this is nmbr frm state: " + this.stateTwo.number);
    const { count } = this.stateTwo;

    console.log("this is : " + count);
    return count === 0 ? "ZERO" : count;
  }

  formatCount() {
    console.log("this is nmbr frm state: " + this.state.count);
    const { count } = this.state;

    console.log("this is : " + count);
    return count === 0 ? "ZERO" : count;
  }
```

Comment: It's `number` in one place and `count` in another.

Comment: Change this line:  const { count } = this.stateTwo;
as const {number} = this.stateTwo or change variable number name in stateTwo as count

Comment: Thank you its working but can you tell me why it is required to keep the const and property name similar ? :)

Comment: Why are you using two states ? You can store your `number` AND your `count` in an unique state.